# Substance LookAndFeel Font Issue

Tags: java, swing, exception, fonts, substance

So, I use one of the Substance LookAndFeel Skins. For version *4.0* of the substance library there was no such issue. However, going on from there, I first noticed it in *4.3*, where it was coming from time to time. Then when I jumped on the newer versions - *6.1* and *7.2.1* it is persistent 100% of the time. Using any other L&Fs gives no problems at all, clearly meaning that the issue is **a bug in Substance**. Searching for it, I saw that some other people were experiencing too.

Sadly, the development is stalled per [this](https://java.net/projects/substance/lists/users/archive/2011-05/message/1).

Yet, the exception states:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics$MetricsKey.init(FontDesignMetrics.java:217)
>       at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(FontDesignMetrics.java:286)
>       at sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.getFontMetrics(SwingUtilities2.java:1113)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.getFontMetrics(JComponent.java:1626)
>       at sun.swing.MenuItemLayoutHelper.reset(MenuItemLayoutHelper.java:126)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthMenuItemLayoutHelper.(SynthMenuItemLayoutHelper.java:119)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthGraphicsUtils.getPreferredMenuItemSize(SynthGraphicsUtils.java:437)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthMenuItemUI.getPreferredMenuItemSize(SynthMenuItemUI.java:216)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.getPreferredSize(BasicMenuItemUI.java:367)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(JComponent.java:1662)
>       at javax.swing.BoxLayout.checkRequests(BoxLayout.java:484)
>       at javax.swing.BoxLayout.preferredLayoutSize(BoxLayout.java:301)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.DefaultMenuLayout.preferredLayoutSize(DefaultMenuLayout.java:60)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthMenuLayout.preferredLayoutSize(SynthMenuLayout.java:51)
>       at java.awt.Container.preferredSize(Container.java:1796)
>       at java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize(Container.java:1780)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(JComponent.java:1664)
>       at javax.swing.JMenu.getPopupMenuOrigin(JMenu.java:377)
>       at javax.swing.JMenu.setPopupMenuVisible(JMenu.java:343)
>       at javax.swing.JPopupMenu.menuSelectionChanged(JPopupMenu.java:1478)
>       at javax.swing.MenuSelectionManager.setSelectedPath(MenuSelectionManager.java:125)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuUI.appendPath(BasicMenuUI.java:222)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuUI.access$200(BasicMenuUI.java:49)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuUI$Handler.mousePressed(BasicMenuUI.java:461)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6532)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4522)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
>       at org.graffiti.editor.GlobalHotkeyManager.dispatchEvent(GlobalHotkeyManager.java:65)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

I know that there is no track of any Substance classes up there, making it even harder to trace.

If anyone knows where I could possibly report it, he/she could gladly share.

It would be a pity, if I would need to abandon it after already investing time in fixing some other nasty bugs or fall back to the last working version - *4.0*, from the distant 2007.

Moreover, the worst part is - there was [a major bugfix](https://java.net/jira/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/SUBSTANCE-344/SUBSTANCE-344.html) regarding InternalFrames in *4.3_02*, effectively falling under the font-buggy versions.

Any advices or fix suggestions?

Comment: after EOL and EndOfInterest, most of developers goes to built JavaFX, most of great minds was refused by Oracle (after merging with Sun)

Answer (score 1):

If this is not not too late for you, please file a bug over at https://github.com/kirill-grouchnikov/substance/issues in case it's happening under the latest 7.1dev builds.

Looks like this happening during the look-and-feel switch between Substance and a Synth-based look-and-feel (Nimbus?). I'd need to see a sample app that reproduces this so that it can be fixed.